# Blue border around png imgae in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, png

I tried using the img border:0 css but no luck.  Please see attached image.  Basically, the gradient image is in png format as a background image.  When I view it on IE 6, there is that blue border showing around that image.  I am puzzled as to why does this only happen on that particular image.

Can anyone please help.  I've been looking for answers but I have not found any luck.

Thanks.

http://www.ofsgraphics.com/images/blueborder.jpg

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the html and css.  provide a link to your page and we might be able to help you.

Comment: blue border would usually indicate the image being treated as a link. Is there a link border-style that's overriding your border:0 rule? You can use stuff like Firefox' Firebug to view the styles/overrides in play on any object.

Comment: Sorry about that... Here is the css for the header bg:

#headerBgGradient {
 background-image:url(../images/gradient_bg.png);
 background-repeat:repeat;
 background-position:0 0;
 height:12px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 margin:121px 0 0 0;
 z-index:10000;
 border:none;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like the image repeating. Not a border.

If the image is a background, try:

```
#your_element {
               background-image: url(your/image.png);
               background-repeat: repeat-x;
              }
```

This will constrain the image repeat to the x axis.

Alternatively, set the element height to the height of the of the background image.

It would be much easier to help if you posted some code.

Comment: Damn! you're the man... it worked, I forgot to specify repeat-x that's why it is acting all weird. Thank you so much!!!